# extract label value for checkbox input object with beautiful soup instead of mechanize in python

Tags: python, html, input, beautifulsoup, mechanize

New to mechanize and BeautifulSoup and am loving it.

I used the prototypical way of opening a URL with mechanize, and I now have the returned object:

```
    def OpenURL(URL, USERAGENT):
        br = Browser()# Create a browser
        br.set_handle_robots(False)   # no robots
        br.set_handle_refresh(False)  # can sometimes hang without this
        br.addheaders = [('User-agent', USERAGENT)]
        #open the URL
        result = br.open(URL)# Open the login page
        return result
```

In my returned result, I have an input object of type "checkbox", name "BoxName". The checkbox has a label. The HTML looks like this:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="BoxName" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
    <label for="BoxName">DESIREDTEXT</label>
```

I am able to get the DESIREDTEXT with mechanize as follows: (code paraphrased to save space)

```
    if control.type == "checkbox": 
        for item in control.items:
            if(control.name == "BoxName"):
                DESIREDTEXT = str([label.text  for label in item.get_labels()])
```

Is there an equivalent way to get the label text value with BeautifulSoup? I am happy to use mechanize to retrieve it, but I just wondered if BeautifulSoup had the ability as well.

addendum  **

HTML from source:

```
    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkCheckedIn" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chkCheckedIn" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkCheckedIn">Checked-In 1/17/2013 1:23:01 AM</label>
```

This is the code where Inbox.read() outputs all the HTML. I verified that the label is there:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(Inbox.read())
print soup.find('label',{'for': 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkCheckedIn'}).text
```

This is my error:

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
```

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    176             else:
    177                 filename = fname
--> 178             **builtin**.execfile(filename, *where)

/home/ubuntu/testAffinity.py in ()
    133         from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
    134         soup = BeautifulSoup(Inbox.read())
--> 135         print soup.find('label',{'for': 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkCheckedIn'}).text
    136 
    137

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Not sure what I'm missing here, but it has to be simple. I notice that the 'for' value is different than the checkbox "name" value. I tried using the checkbox "name" value but received the same error.

** after upgrade to bs4

133         from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    134         soup = BeautifulSoup(Inbox.read())
--> 135         print soup.find('label',{'for': 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkCheckedIn'}).text
    136 
    137

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

**post upgrade to 4
I printed soup. The attribute is correct. The label is in the html from the print soup.

```
    <input checked="checked" disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkCheckedIn" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chkCheckedIn" type="checkbox"/>
    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkCheckedIn">Checked-In 1/17/2013 1:23:01 AM</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just give it a try:

```
soup.find('label',{'for':'BoxName'}).text
```

with your function it would look like:

```
html = OpenURL(URL, USERAGENT).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.find('label',{'for':'BoxName'}).text
```

Comment: That looked promising, however, result is AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Made an addendum. What am I missing here? Has to be obvious.

Comment: I have 3 installed. I tried "pip install --upgrade BeautifulSoup" but version 4 was not installed. (I just learned was pip was two days ago so not sure where to go from here.)

Comment: Comments crossed! I installed 4. Thanks. Same error. How do I make sure that my script is using BS4? Or does pip take care of that?

Comment: Not sure what is going on. I will just use the mechanize method. Thanks for the help. I searched the soup variable for the pertinent html. The attribute is correct. (see post)

Answer (score 0):

Hi are you crawling your page or some other strangers page? otherwise you could use ids in your html and access thought that.

```
tag = BeautifulSoup('<b id="boldest">bold</b>', 'html.parser').b 
tag['id']
# 'boldest'
```

check: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#id13